# Finding the eigenvector of a matrix $2\times 2$ in two ways?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need some help.

I dont understand why the eigenvector $v_1$ of the matrix \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & -2 \end{pmatrix} is the vector $(1,-1)$ and no the vector $(-1,1)$.

$\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = −1$

Comment: what are the eigenvalues?

Comment: When finding a basis of the eigenspace only a set of linearly independent eigenvalues are chosen. In this case you can choose $(1,-1)$ and this one vector forms a basis. But any other vector of the form $a(1,-1)$ (with $a\ne0$) can be chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the vector $(1,-1)$ is just $(-1,1)$ multiplied by $-1$. Indeed, since an eigenvector is a basis vector in the null space of $A-\lambda I$, any scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector.

Or in other words,

$$(A-\lambda I) v = 0 \implies \alpha (A-\lambda I)v  = 0 \implies (A-\lambda I)(\alpha v) = 0$$

for any non-zero scalar $\alpha$.